# Android : WebView onPageFinished not calling after shouldOverrideUrlLoading method in android 4.4

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

I am working on WebView android 4.4 when URL redirect happens loading wheel keep on loading its not dismiss properly. I googled lot but I'm not getting. Can any one explain what is the flow of the WebView android 4.4. Here is my code what I tried :

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading...");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
}
```

Requesting URL "www.google.com". WebView settings are fine. OnpageFinished not calling after shouldOverrideUrlLoading method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a mistake in handling progress dialog.

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        if(dialog == null){
              dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading...");
              dialog.setCancelable(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if(dialog.isShowing())
             dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Now its working fine for all api levels.

Comment: In this case is overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading not necessary. But I guess you are doing something with the url?